# non stick presto electric skillet

Tags: cleaning, non-stick

My skillet is dishwasher safe but it comes out with rust colored spots on the bottom.  The non-stick surface is rough and if I use a paper towel to wipe it down it leaves little pieces of paper behind.

Instructions say not to soak it. It has a sticky feel to it and patches that look and feel like burned on grease.

I feel like I have tried everything. Anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: If the surface is rough, your pan may be damaged beyond salvagability, at least as far as non-stick goes.  Can you give a picture?

Comment: Everything in your description points to the skillet not being dishwasher safe. Where did you get the information that it is dishwasher safe? Could it be that some overenthusiastic seller gave you info on the wrong model?

Answer (score 1):

A rough surface on a non-stick pan sounds like you have used oil or fat in it at a high heat

You do not need to use oil or fat in a non-stick pan, and doing so may result in the polymerisation of the oil or fat into a rough and tough surface

You can remove this by the normal use of a polyester scrubbing bad (green 3M pads) and dish soap. Normal non-stick surfaces are strong enough to resist polyester scrubbers, but polymerised oil is not. I use broad circular scrubbing patterns to avoid wearing out one spot when "fixing" a non-stick pan